# unable to insert data in MYSQL using session and INSERT QUERY

Tags: php, mysql

I have two forms user_details.php and proposal_details.php. I have two tables: users and proposal_details for respective forms.

users table:

```
user_id: INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT

name: varchar(50)

website: varchar(50)...etc..

proposal_details table:

proposal_id: INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT

user_id: INT FOREIGN KEY...REFERENCE FROM user_details(user_id)...etc
```

I have stored user_id in a session variable in following way:

user_details.php

```
session_start();
$run = "SELECT user_id FROM Users WHERE user_id = '$_POST[user_id]'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$run);
$row1= mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$_SESSION['use_id']= $row1['user_id'];
header("location:proposal_details.php");
exit;
```

I am trying to insert the data into proposal_details table in following way:

proposal_details.php

```
<?php
$proposal= $_POST['proposal'];
$proposal_type= $_POST['proposal_type'];
$proposal_template= $_POST['proposal_template'];
$deadline= $_POST['deadline'];
$currency= $_POST['currency'];
$client_name= $_POST['client_name'];
$client_email= $_POST['client_email'];
$comp_name= $_POST['comp_name'];
$website= $_POST['website'];
$txt= $_POST['txt'];
$Country= $_POST['Country'];
$state= $_POST['state'];
$city= $_POST['city'];
$zip= $_POST['zip'];

/*echo $proposal."<br>";
echo $proposal_type."<br>";
echo $proposal_template."<br>";
echo $deadline."<br>";
echo $currency."<br>";
echo $client_name."<br>";
echo $client_email."<br>";
echo $comp_name."<br>";
echo $website."<br>";
echo $txt."<br>";
echo $Country."<br>";
echo $state."<br>";
echo $city."<br>";
echo $zip."<br>";*/



if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

$user_id = $_SESSION['use_id'];
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db"); 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `proposal_details`(`user_id`, `proposal_name`, `proposal_type`, `proposal_template`, `deadline`, `currency`, `client_name`, `email`, `client_company`, `file_upload`, `website`, `address`, `country`, `state`, `city`, `zipcode`) VALUES

(`$user_id`,`$proposal`,`$proposal_type`,`$proposal_template`,`$deadline`,`$currency`,`$client_name`,`$client_email`,`$comp_name`,`$filePath`,`$website`,`$txt`,`$Country`,`$state`,`$city`,`$zip`)";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);


}


/* if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
validatedata();
insert_data();
//header("location:sections.php");
//exit;
} */
?>


 <h1>WELCOME <?php if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();} echo $_SESSION['username']."!"; ?> </h1>
```

when I am echoing the values, the values are printed. But the INSERT query is not getting executed in proposal_details.php

Any ideas what I am missing..because I am stuck for 1 hour now.

Comment: `mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: @user007 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_db`.`proposal_details`, CONSTRAINT `proposal_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`))

Comment: This means your field `user_id` is a foreign key (linked) to the `users` table and you cannot insert values into `proposal_details.user_id` unless those values are present in `users.user_id` . Are you getting it?

Comment: yes.. user_id is getting generated!

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `proposal_details`(`user_id`, `proposal_name`, `proposal_type`, `proposal_template`, `deadline`, `currency`, `client_name`, `email`, `client_company`, `file_upload`, `website`, `address`, `country`, `state`, `city`, `zipcode`) VALUES

(`$user_id`,`$proposal`,`$proposal_type`,`$proposal_template`,`$deadline`,`$currency`,`$client_name`,`$client_email`,`$comp_name`,`$filePath`,`$website`,`$txt`,`$Country`,`$state`,`$city`,`$zip`)";
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `proposal_details`(`user_id`, `proposal_name`, `proposal_type`, `proposal_template`, `deadline`, `currency`, `client_name`, `email`, `client_company`, `file_upload`, `website`, `address`, `country`, `state`, `city`, `zipcode`) VALUES

('$user_id','$proposal','$proposal_type','$proposal_template','$deadline','$currency','$client_name','$client_email','$comp_name','$filePath','$website','$txt','$Country','$state','$city','$zip')";
```

You have `` for values should be ''

Comment: it doesnt change anything.!

Comment: probably you have single quote in some values which is breaking the query insert. use this if ( ($result = $mysqli->query($con,$sql))===false )
{
 echo "Error in query ".$mysqli->error
  exit();
}  This will tell u the error

Comment: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (my_db.proposal_details, CONSTRAINT proposal_details_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id))

Comment: can u echo the $_SESSION['use_id'] in the proposal_details.php and see what it gives ?

Comment: yes thats because of this line if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
} , put session_start(); at the top of the page and then try

Comment: same error...i have session_start in my <h1> tag also...see my code of proposal_details.php

Comment: can try this ? in user details page after u set the session just echo that value and dont re-direct and see if u get the value.Comment the header() redirect, if shows nothing then do this $_SESSION['use_id']= $_POST['user_id']; and then echo $_SESSION['use_id']; if this now shown meaning u have something wrong in the first query. Make sure to add session_start() on the top of the page do not use that condition if(!isset...)

Comment: yeaa..that did work..putting sessio_start at top of the page. Thank you